# how to get a sql query in a pivot format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to get a simple join query results in a pivot format.

Sharing the sample query:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#t') is not null      
    drop table #t    

create table #t (
    EmpName nvarchar(1000),
    CaseNumber nvarchar(1000),
    [WeekDay]   nvarchar(1000)
)

insert into #t values ('Sam','SM100','Monday')
insert into #t values ('Sam','SM100','Wednesday')
insert into #t values ('Sam','SM100','Thursday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Monday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Tuesday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Wednesday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Thursday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Friday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Saturday')
insert into #t values ('Peter','PT200','Sunday')

select * from #t

-- Expected output tabular format
```

From [John's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407921/how-to-get-a-sql-query-in-a-pivot-format/55408096#55408096) query...

```
;with cte as
(
Select * 
 From (Select *,Val=1 From #t) src
 Pivot (sum(Val) for weekday in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday]) )pvt
 )
 select EmpName, CaseNumber, 
 Case When Sunday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Sunday,'') = '' then 'No' end Sunday,
 Case When Monday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Monday,'') = '' then 'No' end Monday,
 Case When Tuesday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Tuesday,'') = '' then 'No' end Tuesday,
 Case When Wednesday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Wednesday,'') = '' then 'No' end Wednesday,
 Case When Thursday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Thursday,'') = '' then 'No' end Thursday,
 Case When Friday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Friday,'') = '' then 'No' end Friday,
 Case When Saturday = 1 then 'Yes' when isnull(Saturday,'') = '' then 'No' end Saturday 
  from cte
```

I prefer not to use too many case statements...

Comment: Maybe you need to use `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this ?

**Example**

```
Select EmpName
      ,CaseNumber
      ,[Sunday]   = IsNull([Sunday],'No')
      ,[Monday]   = IsNull([Monday],'No')
      ,[Tuesday]  = IsNull([Tuesday],'No')
      ,[Wednesday]= IsNull([Wednesday],'No')
      ,[Thursday] = IsNull([Thursday],'No')
      ,[Friday]   = IsNull([Friday],'No')
      ,[Saturday] = IsNull([Saturday],'No')
 From  (Select *,Val='Yes' From #t) src
 Pivot (max(Val) for weekday in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday]) )pvt
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: thank you.. This helps a lot. instead of using the val = 1, where can i change that by applying case when val = 1 then yes when isnull(val,'') = '' then no end   - Just to keep Yes or No. Instead of value

Comment: @goofyui Wasn't sure what your desired results should be.  But you can change Val='Yes' and sum(Val) to max(Val)

Comment: @goofyui Always happy to help  :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
    EmpName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Sunday'    THEN CaseNumber END) AS Sunday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Monday'    THEN CaseNumber END) AS Monday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Tuesday'   THEN CaseNumber END) AS Tuesday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Wednesday' THEN CaseNumber END) AS Wednesday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Thursday'  THEN CaseNumber END) AS Thursday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Friday'    THEN CaseNumber END) AS Friday,
    MAX(CASE WHEN WeekDay = 'Saturday'  THEN CaseNumber END) AS Saturday
FROM #t 
GROUP BY EmpName
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfdab4b6461846a43b8fe3c02aef7e81)** with your sample data:

```
EmpName | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday
:------ | :----- | :----- | :------ | :-------- | :------- | :----- | :-------
Peter   | PT200  | PT200  | PT200   | PT200     | PT200    | PT200  | PT200   
Sam     | null   | SM100  | null    | SM100     | SM100    | null   | null
```

Comment: Thank you.. it works.. i wasnt sure, whether we need an aggregate function

Comment: *" i wasnt sure, whether we need an aggregate function "* If you want to keep database portability @goofyui i suggest using this one over using `PIVOT()` .. You only have to remove `#` to port this query to a other database vendor.